# MySQL stored procedure create database by month

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm a systems admin, and I'm not a dba, I'm wondering if I could use MySQL stored procedure to
Query main database and move records by month to another database located on the same system.

This way we can maintain database small main database, and have data moved to individual database by month.

Thank you

Comment: It's kind of hard to answer this question because deleting data by month is really a business decision. The implementation of such a Stored Procedure would depend on which tables have a timestamp column. Tables that do not have a timestamp column must be copied as is.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to take a look at [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) if you are running a recent version of MySQL and see if this could solve your problem.

Partitioning does not result in a smaller database but offers many of the same benefits with less administration once it is set up, and you will still have access to historic data.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a stored procedure, I would suggest a script or batch file doing the trick. You can do the following.

Rename the current db as oldDB(Name goes with your choice).

```
RENAME DATABASE database_name TO old_database_name;
```

Then restore the structure from the recently renamed db to create original db

```
mysqldump -u [username] –p[password] –no-data [old_database_name] > | mysql -u [username] –p[password] -C [database_name]
```

Have a try.